# Language of all strings that has exactly 1 triple b

Tags: string, automation, regular-language, finite-automata

I am new to automata and learning to make regular expression for languages. But I have been stuck on this one.

Suppose we have a language L, Language of all strings that has exactly 1 triple **“b”** defined over alphabet set **Σ = {a, b}**
Now after several tries, I came up with this
**(a* (ab)* (ba)* )* bbb (a* (ab)* (ba)* )***
but then I realize that this is wrong too because the string **abbbabababb** doesn't fit on this.

Kindly someone point out at my mistake or help me solve it as I have spent almost an hour on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a DFA that describes the language:

```
States: start, b, bb, bbb, bbba, bbbab, bbbabb, x
Accepting: bbb, bbba, bbbab, bbbabb
Transitions: 
  start, a, start
  start, b, b
  b, a, start
  b, b, bb
  bb, a, start
  bb, b, bbb
  bbb, a, bbba
  bbb, b, x
  bbba, a, bbba
  bbba, b, bbbab
  bbbab, a, bbba
  bbbab, b, bbbabb
  bbbabb, a, bbba
  bbbabb, b, x
```

([Example of this DFA in action](http://welbog.ca/dfa/#s=start,false%0Ab,false%0Abb,false%0Abbb,true%0Abbba,true%0Abbbab,true%0Abbbabb,true%0Ax,false&t=start,%20a,%20start%0Astart,%20b,%20b%0Ab,%20a,%20start%0Ab,%20b,%20bb%0Abb,%20a,%20start%0Abb,%20b,%20bbb%0Abbb,%20a,%20bbba%0Abbb,%20b,%20x%0Abbba,%20a,%20bbba%0Abbba,%20b,%20bbbab%0Abbbab,%20a,%20bbba%0Abbbab,%20b,%20bbbabb%0Abbbabb,%20a,%20bbba%0Abbbabb,%20b,%20x&mt=500&ms=120&))

From there, you can [convert the DFA into a regular expression](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions), though you'll omit the x 'dump' state when using this algorithm. You'll end up with an expression something like

```
(|a|ba|bba)*(bbb|bbba(|a|ba|bba)*(|b|bb))
```